# wkhtmltopdf Batch Convert cmd command line

Tags: html, windows, pdf

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf to convert a folder on my pc full of .html files to .pdf files, does anyone know the correct cmd command line to use to successfully have wkhtmltopdf locate the folder where the .html files are and convert and output them to .pdf in the folder of my choice on my pc, also is there a wildcard command so I don't have to put the names of each .html as the folder has over 140k html files. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have tweaked some code in a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527810/wkhtmltopdf-in-batch-file) and used this before:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.html) do "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" 
"%%i"  "C:\temp\html\done\%%~ni.pdf"
```

You can run this from a batch file rather than the command prompt. Replace C:\temp\html\done\ with the folder you want the pdf's to be in and run the batch file from the folder in which the original html's are.